# How can I read and write XML file with JavaScript in my cordova app?

Tags: javascript, android, visual-studio-2013, resources, visual-studio-cordova

I use Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova to build my android app with HTML5 and JavaScript.

I stored a xml file into the res folder: `/res/xml/myFile.xml`.

Now I simply want to read and write the content in this xml file.

Through the VS-plugin manager I already added the File plugin to the config.xml, which added `<vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.3.1" />`

I already searched for tutorials like on [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html), but not for my situation with above mentioned IDE.

So how can I read and write XML file with JavaScript in my cordova app?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you store your xml inside a javascript variable.

```
var xmlvar = "<xml><item name='name1' value='value1' />....</xml>"
```

And then parse it:

```
$('item', xmlvar).each(function(i) {
   //do something - maybe:  var itemname = $(this).attr("name");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to use the xml for dynamic storage, means the content will change and shall be available next app start.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it from **res** folder but if you have it outside in `/xml/myFile.xml` then you can do this to get the file:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
    // parse and use xml here, for example:
    e.target.responseXML; // or responseText
});

xhr.open('GET', 'xml/myFile.xml', true);
xhr.send();
```